# GitHub-actions OR operator for needs clause

Tags: github-actions

Someone knows if it is possible to use OR operator in `needs` statement? let's say we expect a successful job-a OR job-b to run job-c, i.e.

```
name: My workflow
on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  job-a:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: do something
        run: echo "something"
  job-b:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: do something
        run: echo "something"
  job-c:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs:
      - job-a OR job-b
    steps:
      - name: do something
        run: echo "something"
```

Comment: Create an additional job which checks periodically if job a or b has finished?

Answer (score 30):

Yes it's possible. Unfortunately I have some cases where it doesn't always works as expected. But the idea is to do something as follow:

```yaml
jobs:
  job-a:
    name: Job A
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: true

  job-b:
    name: Job B
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: false
    steps:
      - run: true

  job-ab:
    name: Job AB
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: [ job-a, job-b ]
    if: |
      always()
      && contains(needs.*.result, 'success')
      && !contains(needs.*.result, 'failure')
    steps:
      - run: true
```

By default when using `needs`, any job in the dependency list that is skipped will trigger a skip of the current job. If you want to force the job to run you have to use the `always()` function which will tell your job to always run. Unfortunately this means that it will run event if a job fails or if all the previous jobs are skipped. `contains(needs.*.result, 'success')` will be true if at least one of the jobs succeeded. So if all your jobs are skipped it will be false. `!(contains(needs.*.result, 'failure'))` is false if any job failed

I am a more detailed demo [here](https://github.com/benjamin-bergia/github-workflow-patterns/blob/master/.github/workflows/ignore-skipped.yml).

Comment: This works as long as you don't have any other jobs which need job-ab.

Comment: @CraigAnderson, that is correct. Any job that needs `job-ab` will need to use `if: always() && needs.job-ab.result == 'success'`. Unfortunately, you need to propagate this logic to all downstream jobs :-/

Comment: I wonder if we could now work around this by calling a reusable workflow in job-ab that would include all jobs depending on job-a and job-b. I didn't test it but I don't expect it to require the if expression in all the jobs of the reusable workflow.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine [jobs.<job_id>.outputs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjobs_idoutputs), [jobs.<job_id>.steps[*].if](https://docs.github.com/pt/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#), and [jobs.<job_id>.needs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idneeds):

```
jobs:
  job1:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      output1: ${{ steps.step1.outputs.test }}
    steps:
      - id: step0
        run: echo "something"

      - id: step1
        if: success()
        run: echo "::set-output name=test::success"

  job2:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      output2: ${{ steps.step1.outputs.test }}
    steps:
      - id: step0
        run: echo "something"

      - id: step1
        if: success()
        run: echo "::set-output name=test::success"

  job3:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: [job1, job2]
    if: needs.job1.outputs.output1 == 'success' && needs.job2.outputs.output2 == 'success'
    steps:
      - run: echo ${{needs.job1.outputs.output1}} ${{needs.job2.outputs.output2}}
```

Basically, on each job, your last step will set an output only if the other steps succeeded.

And then you can access those outputs through any job and do anything you want.

Comment: This doesn't work. The steps context only has access to the steps of the current job not across jobs. https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#steps-context

Comment: Ǵood point. I just updated the post with an alternative. This time I have tested the code.

Comment: `needs.job1.outputs.output1 == 'success' && needs.job2.outputs.output2 == 'success'` Maybe `&&` should be replaced with `||`?

Answer (score 1):

your job will always run if you use "if: ${{ always()" regardless on "needs"

Comment: Works for me when having 2 parallel jobs [a, b] thats in the end run [c] from a or b.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to have a true OR condition in `needs`, but there are plenty of ways to work around this limitation. My workaround was to make each job run, but to check whether each step should run.

```yaml
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - "main"
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  job-a:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - if: ${{ github.event_name == 'pull_request' }}
        run: echo "Triggered by a pull request"

  job-b:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - if: ${{ github.event_name == 'workflow_dispatch' }}
        run: echo "Triggered by workflow dispatch"

  job-c:
    needs: [job-a, job-b]
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: echo "Do some stuff"

  job-d:
    needs: [job-c]
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: echo "This runs too"
```